# uiveri5:- Site authentication through spec file not through conf.js

Tags: protractor, sapui5

Through uiveri5, I am trying to log in to the website with different users depending upon their roles from spec file. If i go by conf.js authentication then i can only login once with one user during runtime. If i try through spec file i am getting ui5 not found on page error. Is there any way to achieve above without conf.js

I have tried authenticating through spec but got ui5 not found error.
Code for the same is

```
    browser.get(url);
    // browser.sleep(2000);
    element(by.css('.saml-login-link')).click();
    browser.sleep(2000);
    element(by.css('#j_username')).sendKeys(username);
    element(by.css('#j_password')).sendKeys(password);
    element(by.css('#logOnFormSubmit')).click();
```

Comment: You can add as another testcase know?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is very easy - just disable the declarative authentication by setting baseUrl: null and then execute programmatic authentication as described here: https://github.com/SAP/ui5-uiveri5/blob/master/docs/config/authentication.md.
And please forget the usage of those sleep() calls in uiveri5 tests, the whole point of this framework is to avoid the usage of explicit synchronization with sleeps and waits in tests for UI5 applications.